# How to turn off highlighting/colors for changes/current edits?

Tags: colorscheme, highlight, macos

Recently (within the past year?) vim has started tracking changes as I edit, and highlighting those changes with a different color.  I've given it a try, but I'd like to turn that specific feature off without turning of all highlighting due to syntax (since I still use syntax and colorscheme).  How do I turn off just the "track changes" highlighting?

[image: change highlighting]

Version info:

```
vi --version
VIM - Vi IMproved 9.0 (2022 Jun 28, compiled Nov 13 2022 20:35:12)
macOS version - arm64
Included patches: 1-639
Compiled by root@apple.com
Normal version without GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
+acl               +file_in_path      -mouse_urxvt       -tag_any_white
-arabic            +find_in_path      +mouse_xterm       -tcl
+autocmd           +float             +multi_byte        -termguicolors
+autochdir         +folding           +multi_lang        +terminal
-autoservername    -footer            -mzscheme          +terminfo
-balloon_eval      +fork()            +netbeans_intg     +termresponse
-balloon_eval_term -gettext           +num64             +textobjects
-browse            -hangul_input      +packages          +textprop
++builtin_terms    +iconv             +path_extra        +timers
+byte_offset       +insert_expand     -perl              +title
+channel           +ipv6              +persistent_undo   -toolbar
+cindent           +job               +popupwin          +user_commands
-clientserver      +jumplist          +postscript        -vartabs
+clipboard         -keymap            +printer           +vertsplit
+cmdline_compl     +lambda            -profile           +vim9script
+cmdline_hist      -langmap           -python            +viminfo
+cmdline_info      +libcall           -python3           +virtualedit
+comments          +linebreak         +quickfix          +visual
-conceal           +lispindent        +reltime           +visualextra
+cryptv            +listcmds          -rightleft         +vreplace
+cscope            +localmap          +ruby/dyn          +wildignore
+cursorbind        -lua               +scrollbind        +wildmenu
+cursorshape       +menu              +signs             +windows
+dialog_con        +mksession         +smartindent       +writebackup
+diff              +modify_fname      -sodium            -X11
+digraphs          +mouse             -sound             -xfontset
-dnd               -mouseshape        +spell             -xim
-ebcdic            -mouse_dec         +startuptime       -xpm
-emacs_tags        -mouse_gpm         +statusline        -xsmp
+eval              -mouse_jsbterm     -sun_workshop      -xterm_clipboard
+ex_extra          -mouse_netterm     +syntax            -xterm_save
+extra_search      +mouse_sgr         +tag_binary        
-farsi             -mouse_sysmouse    -tag_old_static    
   system vimrc file: "$VIM/vimrc"
     user vimrc file: "$HOME/.vimrc"
 2nd user vimrc file: "~/.vim/vimrc"
      user exrc file: "$HOME/.exrc"
       defaults file: "$VIMRUNTIME/defaults.vim"
  fall-back for $VIM: "/usr/share/vim"
Compilation: gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H   -DMACOS_X_UNIX  -g -O2 -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1      
Linking: gcc   -L/usr/local/lib -o vim        -lm -lncurses  -liconv -framework Cocoa
```

Comment: It doesn't do it out of the box, afaik. Is it a plugin maybe?

Comment: Maybe.  I'm using vi provided by Apple on a Mac, will update question to include version information.

Comment: And a screenshot maybe? :)

Comment: Thanks for looking at this question.  Screenshot added.

Comment: Does it happen with `vim -Nu NONE file.txt`? EDIT, I guess not, because syntax hl would be turned off.

Comment: No, but that also seems to turn off all syntax highlighting on different types of files.  {:hi clear} also turns it off, but I suspect that turns off all highlighting (but not all colors).

Comment: My assumption that this is highlighting changes may not be correct.  If I change the colorscheme the highlights go away (and don't return).  My default colo is elflord which is the light blue text... it it seems the issue is reversed.  The "old text" is a color other than my colorscheme, and new text is written in the right color.  Changing colorscheme removes the difference.  Is this a "bug" of some sort with the Apple vim?

Comment: It looks like an issue with vim related to OSX, I remember I saw it in github

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First 2 lines have different colors...

Looks like it is known issue https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/10521 related only to vim in Terminal.app.

Comment: Yep, looks like the same issue.  I confirmed that it is in fact only happening in Terminal.app after downloading another terminal emulator.  I misunderstood this to be an added feature of vim.